# What is the subject in the sentence "there is a lot of X?" and how do I determine subject-verb agreement?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I was told that the sentence "there is a lot of potatoes" is incorrect because potatoes is a countable noun, so it should be "there are a lot of potatoes". But if I analyze the grammar,  "lot" seems to be the nucleus of the noun phrase, therefore the verb should agree with the singular form ("is" instead of "are"). Which of these is correct?

I got reprimanded by my teaching supervisor over this so I'd appreciate some sources regarding the correct answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google **collective nouns verb agreement**, which is what your query is about. You will find numerous sites that throw useful light on the subject. In practice, English speakers frequently use the introduction **There is...** to introduce plurals. **There's (a lot of) troubles/potholes/warnings ahead!** I'm not advocating it, just mentioning it. Your teacher is being  a mite pedantic.

Comment: That's super helpful! According to what I could find, it seems collective nouns can take either singular or plural verbs depending on whether they refer to the members collectively or individually. If that's the case, "lot" definitely feels more like the former.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *There is* [*a lot of snow everywhere*].
>
> [2] *There are* [*a lot of errors in this book*].

Both examples are existential clauses whose subject is the dummy pronoun "there". "There" has no inherent number but takes on the number of the displaced subject, here bracketed.

The bracketed noun phrases have "lot" as head, with the *of* phrases as its complement. "Lot" is said to be 'number-transparent' in that the verb-form is determined not by the head ("lot") but by the noun that is complement of the preposition "of".

In [1] "snow" is a non-count noun and thus singular, so singular "is" is the correct verb. In [2] "errors" is a plural count noun so plural "are" is correct.

Note that in informal style with reduced *is*, many speakers treat "there" as always singular: they say "There's a lot of errors" instead of "There are a lot of errors".

Comment: I couldn't find any sources on "lot" being 'number-transparent', do you have any suggestions for further reading on that?

Comment: @MartínAlonso This may help [link](http://english-jack.blogspot.com/2011/12/number-transparency-and-determiner.html)

Answer (score 0):

The blank in "a lot of ___" doesn't modify "a lot", instead it forms a complete noun phrase. And that phrase can be either countable or uncountable.

Imagine that instead of potatoes your phrase is "a lot of time", you could easily have a sentence like "There is a lot of time remaining.", or "There is a lot of spaghetti". Unlike potatoes both time and spaghetti are uncountable and the sentence would therefore have an "is".

The reason potatoes are countable while time and spaghetti are not is that you can slice both time and spaghetti into smaller pieces without really changing their nature. The same is not true of potatoes. You cut a potato and you are left with potato chunks or slices, but not actual potatoes.

Comment: I understand countables vs uncountables, but isn't "of potatoes" a prepositional phrase in this case? If that's true then it shouldn't be able to conjugate the verb.
If you said instead " a _group_ of people" or "a _crowd_ of people", would you still use "are"?

Comment: I would use "is" with both "group of people" and "crowd of people" (There is a group of people"/"There is a crowd of people" - although I might leave "of people off entirely in the "crowd" case). The members of a group/crowd are of a very different nature than the aggregate.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in English we treat _spaghetti_ as a substance and therefore uncountable, even though in Italian it's a plural noun.

Answer (score 0):

The OED has this to say, which may be useful

> **Lot**
>
> **V.** A large number or amount.
>
> **V.18.a.** With of-phrase as complement. The phrases a lot of and lots of
> are sometimes regarded as phrasal determiners (functioning similarly
> to much and many); grammatical agreement is normally
> with the noun following of rather than with the form of lot

Source: Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “lot (n.),” December 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/9797470075.

I note the use of **sometimes** here, which to me would imply that it's not a rule set in stone. In any case "a lot of" is quite colloquial/informal anyway.  Therefore, I would say that in your examples either **is/are** could be used. Native English speakers do  say things like "There's a lot of potatoes".  It's fairly common.  A quick google ngram search will reveal several examples using *There's a lot of +[plural noun]*.